# spring batch: restarting a completed job with same parameters

Tags: spring-batch

Is it possible to restart a job in spring batch with same job params, which has completed successfully?

Say I have a job with a step which reads from one file and writes to another.

For test purpose, I need to run the job again and again. However, I do not want the job param (which is today's date which I am reading from a table) to change again and again.

Is such a scenario possible ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Long startNextInstance(String jobName) 
      throws NoSuchJobException, JobParametersNotFoundException, JobRestartException, 
             JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException;
```

This method of the JobOperator class along with a JobParameterIncrementer can be used to restart a job, either failed or completed.

http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/launch/support/SimpleJobOperator.html#startNextInstance(java.lang.String)

Comment: I still cannot understand, why some logic is located in `JobOperator` and some in `JobLauncher`. As for me these two should be merged. Finally I've created the semantically equivalent code of [`startNextInstance()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.batch/spring-batch-core/2.1.8.RELEASE/org/springframework/batch/core/launch/support/SimpleJobOperator.java#SimpleJobOperator.startNextInstance%28java.lang.String%29) in [my project](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?107268-How-to-reset-a-stale-running-job-restart-a-completed-job#post358384).

Comment: @dma_k - I can fully relate to your frustration with how the APIs are dispersed in several classes. I really cannot understand how these APIs ever made it out without a very valid reason for doing so.

Comment: @MatthewCachia https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/spring-batch-intro.html#springBatchBackground

*Citing:* Accenture has contributed previously proprietary batch processing architecture frameworks, based upon decades worth of experience in building batch architectures with the last several generations of platforms, (i.e., COBOL/Mainframe, C++/Unix, and now Java/anywhere) to the Spring Batch project along with committer resources to drive support, enhancements, and the future roadmap.

Comment: @dma_k The JobOperator interface is a JSR-352 requirement. We all know that Spring batch precedes the JSR and a lot of functional overlap is inevitable

Answer (score 6):

Spring Batch requires unique job parameters for its execution.so you can add the current time as a job parameter

```
Map<String, JobParameter> confMap = new HashMap<String, JobParameter>();
confMap.put("time", new JobParameter(System.currentTimeMillis()));
JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParameters(confMap);
jobLauncher.run(springCoreJob, jobParameters);
```

Answer (score 4):

Spring Batch requires unique job parameters for its execution.
In your case, if you want to run the same job with the same date parameter, than you should "add" another job parameter to make it unique. You may think of it unique job parameter set.

`org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersIncrementer` interface can be used in this scenario, just give it your JobParameter and it will add a run.id that will make it unique.

```
public class SampleIncrementer implements JobParametersIncrementer {  

    public JobParameters getNext(JobParameters parameters) { 
        if (parameters==null || parameters.isEmpty()) {
            return new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("run.id", 1L).toJobParameters();
        }
        long id = parameters.getLong("run.id",1L) + 1;
        return new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("run.id", id).toJobParameters();
    } }
```

You may check [a simple sample using it](http://numberformat.wordpress.com/2010/02/07/multiple-batch-runs-with-spring-batch/)

Comment: Spring Batch has a class that already does this: [org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/launch/support/RunIdIncrementer.html)

Comment: "Spring Batch requires unique job parameters for its execution" => that requirement doesn't make any sense to me

Answer (score 0):

I have this function

```
public void run()
{
    LOG.info("Processing batch...");
    try
    {
        Job job = createNewJob();
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParameters();
        Optional<JobInstance> existingInstance = jobExplorer.getJobInstances(job.getName(), 0, 1).stream().findFirst();
        if (existingInstance.isPresent())
        {
            jobParameters = job.getJobParametersIncrementer().getNext(jobParameters);
            LOG.warn("Trying to restart task \"{}\" with the parameters [{}]", job, jobParameters);
        }
        jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
    }
    catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException ex)
    {
        LOG.warn("The task \"{}\" is already running", BillingBatchConfig.QUALIFIER);
    }
    catch (JobRestartException ex)
    {
        LOG.warn("The task \"{}\" cannot be restarted", BillingBatchConfig.QUALIFIER);
    }
    catch (JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException ex)
    {
        LOG.warn("The task \"{}\" cannot be restarted cause its finished", BillingBatchConfig.QUALIFIER);
    }
    catch (JobParametersInvalidException ex)
    {
        LOG.warn("The task \"{}\" cannot be excecuted cause the parameters are invalid", BillingBatchConfig.QUALIFIER);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LOG.warn("Unexpected error running the task \"{}\"", BillingBatchConfig.QUALIFIER);
    }
}
```

The key is to check first if there is an existing instance of `org.springframework.batch.core.explore.JobExplorer` in the database of the wanted job. If its so, the job must be started using the parameters obtained by `job.getJobParametersIncrementer().getNext(jobParameters)`. Thats all.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the same idea as Serkan Arıkuşu.

My batch can **restart with same parameters** by adding **by the inside** each time a **unique** parameter (*timestamp.*)

I do this with creating a `JobParametersIncrementer`.

### Here the code sample:

***The incrementer:***

```
package com.batch;

import java.util.Date;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersIncrementer;


public class MyIncrementer implements JobParametersIncrementer {

  public JobParameters getNext(JobParameters parameters) {
   long id = new Date().getTime();
   JobParameters jParam = new JobParametersBuilder()
        .addLong("run.id", id).toJobParameters();

   return jParam;
  }
 }
```

---

***The additional content in the XML of the job:***

```
<bean id="myIncrementer" class="com.batch.MyIncrementer"/>

<job id="myJob" ... restartable="true" incrementer="myIncrementer">
    <step ... >
    <tasklet ...>
        <chunk ... />
        ...
    </tasklet>
   </step>
   <batch:listeners>
    ...
   </batch:listeners>
</job>
```

### Here the screenshot

[image]